# how to give a .bat code line a time limit?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I want to put a 30s time limit for the `:choice Y/N/P` and after the time is up `goto :start`

The code I have need help for the timeing thing

```
@echo off
:start
echo AmishCraft will start
TIMEOUT /T 5
echo (%time%)
java -Xms2048M -Xmx4096M -jar server.jar

call C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe

ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 3000 >nul 

:choice 
set /P a=do you want to restart? Yes No Pause [Y/N/P]?
if /I "%a%" EQU "Y" goto :restart
if /I "%a%" EQU "N" goto :stop
if /I "%a%" EQU "P" goto :pause
goto :start

:restart
cls
echo server will restart
 
cls
goto :start

:stop

cls
echo closing server
TIMEOUT /T 5
exit

cls
echo server is paused 
:pause
:choice 
set /P a=do you want start? Restart Stop [R/S]?
if /I "%a%" EQU "R" goto :restart
if /I "%a%" EQU "S" goto :stop
goto :start

pause
```

Comment: Well, as an alternative to `set /P`, take a look at the [`choice` command](https://ss64.com/nt/choice.html), which features a timeout option (`/T`)...

Answer (score 2):

- `/T` is the **timeout** switch for choice.
- `/D` is the **switch** to define the **default errorlevel / option** to set if the
  time Elapses.

Example:

`CHOICE /T 5 /N /C 1234 /M "Select Option 1,2,3 or 4" /D 1`

Applies a timeout of 5 seconds, with the errorlevel being set to option 1, equal to errorlevel 1 in this instance.

- `/N` Hides the default Choice Prompt String.
- `/M` Allows you to Define your own Prompt string
- `/C` Allows alphanumerical characters to be defined as Choice options

Note:

- Errorlevel is Set from Left to Right with regards to listed options.
- After the Choice Command Errorlevel Needs to be Assessed From Highest to lowest
- OR
- Used Directly; Such as in a `Goto :LabelName%errorlevel%` Command

*** Response to comment ***

```
CHOICE /C 123 /T Timeout 25 /D goto :start /M 1 choice menu 25s
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 1 goto :choice1
```

There are multiple errors in the above.

- `/T Timeout 25` should be: `/T 25`
- `Timeout` is implicit in the `/T` switch and does NOT form a part of correct usage of the choice command.
- `/D goto :start` should be: `/D 1` OR `/D 2` OR `/D 3`
- Only the defined `/C` options should be used following the **`/D`** switch
- `/M 1 choice menu 25s` is incorrect.
- The prompt after `/M` should be encased in Doublequotes: **`"[1] Option 1. [2] Option 2. [3] Option 3."`**
- Errorlevel Assessment should be done on the Line After the CHOICE Command.
- Again, to be clear, **Assesment should be done from Highest to Lowest**. When errorlevel is Assessed following Choice it is actually interpreted as **`If ERRORLEVEL GTR n`** , Despite being scripted Using `If ERRORLEVEL n`

An example of the Correct usage of all of the above:

```
@echo off
:menu
cls
CHOICE /N /T 25 /C 123 /M "[1] Option 1. [2] Option 2. [3] Start." /D 3
    IF ERRORLEVEL 3 (
        GOTO :start
    ) else (
        GOTO :choice%errorlevel%
    )

:start
ECHO( You are at the start
Pause
GOTO :menu

:choice1
ECHO( You are at option 1
Pause
GOTO :menu

:choice2
ECHO( You are at option 2
Pause
GOTO :menu
```

Comment: i cant get it to work                                                                                              
CHOICE /C 123 /T Timeout 25 /D goto :start /M 1 choice menu 25s
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 1 goto :choice1                                                       
 this is what is get                                                                                                                                        ERROR: Invalid argument/option - '25'.
Type "CHOICE /?" for usage.

Comment: Please update your question with the failed attempt and format the code correctly with quoting `code` so it is actually readable. There are obvious errors in the way you've attempted to use the Choice command. which I'll adress in my answer

Comment: reconsider `IF ERRORLEVEL ==3` (works but is syntactically wrong)

Comment: Dropped the == to Keep in line with Usage recommended here: `https://www.robvanderwoude.com/errorlevel.php`